# Using pygerrit to get robot-comments from gerrit url is failing

Tags: python, json, gerrit

Im trying to write a small application that extract robot comments from a content of a gerrit url:

```
rest = GerritRestAPI(url=options.gerrit_url, auth=HTTPDigestAuth(raw_input("username: "), raw_input("Password: ")), verify=True)

try:
    changes = rest.get("gerrit/#/c/{change_id}/robotcomments")
    logging.info("%d changes", len(changes))
    for change in changes:
        logging.info(change['change_id'])
except RequestException as err:
    logging.error("Error: %s", str(err))
```

I followed the rest-api to get robot comments data, 
https://gerrit-review.googlesource.com/Documentation/rest-api-changes.html#list-change-robot-comments

and for some reason I get an 404 error that page do not exists.
do anyone know how to use pygerrit to get information from url regrading a commit?

I tried so many addition to url in the call `rest.get("gerrit/#/c/{change_id}/robotcomments")`, either `change/{change_id}/robotcomments`
or `gerrit/#/c/{change_id}/robotcomments` none of them worked, what I also saw is that calling `rest.get` adds 'a' to the url so I tried to use the underling code instead of pygerrit:

```
url = "https/{gerrit_url}/gerrit/#/c/{change_id}/robotcomments"
myResponse = requests.get(url, auth=HTTPDigestAuth(raw_input("username: "), raw_input("Password: ")), verify=True)
print(myResponse.text)
```

this is also failing, please let me know what am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

Looking at the [Gerrit documentation](https://gerrit-review.googlesource.com/Documentation/rest-api-changes.html#list-change-robot-comments), it seems that you should use:

```
rest.get("/changes/{change_id}/robotcomments")
```

Instead of:

```
rest.get("gerrit/#/c/{change_id}/robotcomments")
```

Comment: The correct URL is: GERRIT-SERVER/a/changes/{change_id}/robotcomments. The "a" is added automatically, but do not forget the "/" at the beginning of the rest.get call: rest.get("/changes/{change_id}/robotcomments").

Comment: I do have a GERRIT-SERVER in the beginning and this is already provided  here:  GerritRestAPI(url=options.gerrit_url, auth=HTTPDigestAuth(raw_input("username: "), raw_input("Password: ")), verify=True)

Comment: I know... I'm just asking if you added the "/" at the beginning of "changes/..." in rest.get("/changes/{change_id}/robotcomments") call.